# AliExpress developer account

Tags: c#, api, aliexpress

I am trying to open developer account to get clientid for auth process. It's like redirect process

https://authus.alibaba.com/auth/authorize.htm?client_id=**123456**&
site=aliexpress&redirect_uri=http://returnurl.com&_aop_signature=123456796413131313

Can anyone please let me know the step to open the developer account so can get clientid

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](https://portals.aliexpress.com/help.htm?page=help_center_api&)

Comment: I think this link is just the API help no information to sign up for developer account